# Calculate a Python Array Using For Loops from Data in 2 Dataframes?

Tags: arrays, pandas, loops

I am trying to make or fill a 2-d array using a numpy function called "np.random.normal(average, standard deviation, size)" with the given inputs. My inputs originate from two different dfs that contain the average and standard deviation respectively and they are shown below. This is dfa:

```
    month   site    AvgAdj_Prod
    1       Maple   44
    2       Maple   48
    3       Maple   51
    4       Maple   55
    5       Maple   62
    6       Maple   57
    7       Maple   51
    8       Maple   44
    9       Maple   48
    10      Maple   39
    11      Maple   38
    12      Maple   40
    1         Oak   117
    2         Oak   129
    3         Oak   133
    4         Oak   201
    5         Oak   206
    6         Oak   271
    7         Oak   289
    8         Oak   221
    9         Oak   159
    10        Oak   157
    11        Oak   140
    12        Oak   130
```

The standard deviation df "dfs" looks like this:

```
    month   site    StdevAdj_Prod
    1       Maple   12
    2       Maple   13
    3       Maple   11
    4       Maple   10
    5       Maple   9
    6       Maple   14
    7       Maple   7
    8       Maple   9
    9       Maple   12
    10      Maple   14
    11      Maple   18
    12      Maple   15
    1         Oak   25
    2         Oak   37
    3         Oak   44
    4         Oak   39
    5         Oak   52
    6         Oak   71
    7         Oak   49
    8         Oak   54
    9         Oak   44
    10        Oak   69
    11        Oak   51
    12        Oak   77
```

I am trying to populate a 2-d array for months (rows) and N instances (columns) based on the number of sites - 2 in this case - "Maple' and "Oak". I have tried the following to create the final 2-d array that should have 5 rows for each site because I need to know the output for months 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.

So, the final dataframe of calculations using np.random.normal() should be 10 rows by 5 columns. Here is what I have tried, but my value 'rout' does not append new data but only overwrites the same data. Thank you for your help.

```py
months = list(range(monthnow, 13))  # months == [8,9,10,11,12]
r = []
uniques = df1["site"].unique()  # unique number of sites
n = 5
ns = list(range(1, n + 1))  # of iterations to calculate (columns)
r1 = np.zeros((len(months), n))  # component of np.random.normal(r1,r2,x)
r2 = np.zeros((len(months), n))  # component of np.random.normal(r1,r2,x)
rout = np.zeros((len(months), n))  # 5 x 5 array of output from np.random.normal()
for vals in uniques:
    for i in months:
        for k in range(1, n + 1):
            # print(k)
            for j in ns:
                # print(j)
                r1[k - 1, j - 1] = dfa[(dfa.site == vals)][dfa.month == i]["Adj_Prod"]
                r2[k - 1][j - 1] = dfs[(dfs.plant_name == vals)][dfs.month == i][
                    "Adj_Prod"
                ]
                rout[k - 1, j - 1] = np.random.normal(
                    r1[k - 1, j - 1], r2[k - 1, j - 1], 1
                )
                print(rout)
    r.append(rout)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that `rout` is not reinitialized after being appended.

With the dataframes you provided:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 'site': ['Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak'], 'AvgAdj_Prod': [44, 48, 51, 55, 62, 57, 51, 44, 48, 39, 38, 40, 117, 129, 133, 201, 206, 271, 289, 221, 159, 157, 140, 130]})

dfs = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 'site': ['Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Maple', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak', 'Oak'], 'StdevAdj_Prod': [12, 13, 11, 10, 9, 14, 7, 9, 12, 14, 18, 15, 25, 37, 44, 39, 52, 71, 49, 54, 44, 69, 51, 77]})
```

The following code provides, I think, the result you expect:

```py
months = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
r = []
uniques = dfa["site"].unique()
n = 5
ns = list(range(1, n + 1))
r1 = np.zeros((len(months), n))
r2 = np.zeros((len(months), n))

for val in uniques:
    rout = np.zeros((len(months), n))
    for i in months:
        for k in range(1, n + 1):
            for j in ns:
                r1[k - 1, j - 1] = dfa.loc[
                    (dfa.site == val) & (dfa.month == i), "AvgAdj_Prod"
                ]
                r2[k - 1][j - 1] = dfs.loc[
                    (dfs.site == val) & (dfs.month == i), "StdevAdj_Prod"
                ]
                rout[k - 1, j - 1] = np.random.normal(
                    r1[k - 1, j - 1], r2[k - 1, j - 1], 1
                )
    r.append(rout)
```

```py
print(r)
# Output
[
    array(
        [
            [37.56708627, 11.89442282, 32.79617584, 19.3774222, 41.61703549],
            [41.27896445, 32.82832126, 25.55349053, 54.42646487, 32.02670686],
            [36.37309834, 45.73408605, 34.14421009, 31.62474747, 35.52334414],
            [39.29474075, 41.25229097, 45.93103323, 20.76663807, 34.59076033],
            [54.22060032, 53.5233677, -2.64159211, 46.77896409, 29.19027622],
        ]
    ),
    array(
        [
            [139.68338142, 224.35423705, 91.48533586, 73.78006845, 146.88688503],
            [209.26142311, 69.75640239, 103.79220378, 168.36765205, 91.0073397],
            [20.27003735, 52.15998312, 147.44803278, 8.36811135, 88.59378042],
            [252.16742434, 122.18310833, 169.66181174, 196.28030665, 179.30169691],
            [179.41385097, 29.46613095, 140.79689411, 73.38920373, 176.65458478],
        ]
    ),
]
```